# user roles management in mvc5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have created using seed in mvc5 app some demo users and some roles. Successfully assign user to few roles. Everything works. Now I want but I don't know how to build user management, ui interface which will be responsible for

- Create/Edit users and assign to one or more roles

Roles will be hardcoded (RoleOne, RoleTwo, RoleThree).

I was thinking to create view with custom viewmodel which will take only few properties

```
Username
Password
Email
```

and list of Roles assigned trough checkbox on the view.

Question is: How should I structure this Roles property on viewmodel and how to receive checked roles on the post controller action side?

Comment: You could have a boolean property in the viewmodel for `selected` and in the post, cycle through all checkboxes to see which ones were indeed selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes down to a use case where you want to post a collection of sub items in your viewmodel where the sub items represents a checkbox in the UI.

Create a viewmodel for your view where you will create a user and assign roles at the same time.

```
public class AddUserRoleVM
{
    public string UserName { set; get; }
    public List<UserRoleVM> Roles { set; get; }
    public AddUserRoleVM()
    {
        Roles=new List<UserRoleVM>();
    }
}

public class UserRoleVM
{
    public int RoleId { set; get; }
    public String RoleName { set; get; }
    public bool IsSelected { set; get; }
}
```

Now in your GET action, create an objecct of the `AddUserRoleVM` viewmodel, Initialize the `Roles` collections property and send it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Roles()
{
    var vm = new AddUserRoleVM();
    vm.Roles = GetRoles();
    return View(vm);
}

private List<UserRoleVM> GetRoles()
{
    //Hard coded for demo.You should get the roles from db
    return new List<UserRoleVM>
    {
        new UserRoleVM {RoleId = 1, RoleName = "Admin"},
        new UserRoleVM {RoleId = 2, RoleName = "Editor"}
    };
}
```

Now Create a folder called `EditorTemplates` under `Views/YourControllerName`. Then create a new view under that called `UserRoleVM.cshtml` with below content.

```
@model ReplaceYourNamespaceHere.UserRoleVM
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.RoleId)
    <label>@Model.RoleName</label>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(s=>s.IsSelected)
</div>
```

[image]

Now in our main view (Roles.cshtml), Use `Html.EditorFor` HTML helper method to bring this view.

```
@model YourNameSpaceHere.AddUserRoleVM
<h2>Create User</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <label>UserName : </label> @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.UserName)
    <label>Roles:</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(s=>s.Roles)
    <input type="submit"/>
}
```

Now when you post your form data, Check the Roles collection of your posted model and verify the `IsSelected` property of each item.

[image]

Cheers !